# Getting error: "bad read of inttemp!" when training a new font in Tesseract 2

Tags: java, android, tesseract

I'm trying to train Tesseract for a new font which can be used in my Android app. I need to train for digits only, so I had created one training image, box file and unicharset file.

I have followed [the training instructions](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract2), but when I tried to run tesseract it says, `bad read of inttemp!`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I diagnose this error?

Comment: Training is quite painful. Carefully examine the logs of your training workflow for Warnings and Errors. If something goes wrong your trainingdata is useless.

Comment: @gabe, can you suggest any helpful links?

Comment: I spent alot of time in https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/tesseract-ocr maybe this is something for you https://gitorious.org/ancient-greek-training-for-tesseract/tesstrainingtools

Comment: thanx gabe. i will look in to this :)

Comment: it is for tesseract 3 but maybe it helps http://michaeljaylissner.com/blog/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3-ocr-engine

Comment: http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html a box editor maybe of use

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=155

Turns out, tesseract was still going back to the "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR" folder - including using the 3.0 training exes within the training folder there. It made no difference where I was running the command from - guess tesseract ignores that when it has a path variable.

Replaced all of the 3.0 exe and training files in that folder. Dropped in the 2.0.4 files and the extract command worked!!! I should have solved the problem faster for all sorts of reasons, but..

try this

http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/ocr/tesseract.html